# Copy subset of rows from one sheet to another, based on value in column

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I have a sheet with accounts, consisting of 3 columns:

- Accountnr
- Name
- Category

This sheet is not nescessarily sorted on any column.The Category is one of three possible values.

I want to fill a part of another tab with all the accountnrs of a certain category.
How can i do that? I have been looking at ARRAYFORMULA() but am not sure that that will give me the solution.

Even though i do have fair amount of experience with Excel sheets (until a few years ago), this is my first attempt at Google Sheets ;-)

Any advice is welcome

gr
Bas

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the solution:

```
=QUERY(ACOUNTSHEET!A2:C; "SELECT A WHERE C = 'Cat1'")
```